# Spring boot Jackson Json Serialization for List implementation class (PagedList)

Tags: json, spring-mvc, serialization, spring-boot, jackson

Is there any way to add serialization for list implementing class having custom attributes?

I am working on Rest service using Spring-boot 1.3. I have to return JSON response as **Paged-List** or **Normal-List**, depend on request on Controller. So, I have to keep return type of controller method as generic `public List<Employee> getEmployees(int departmentId)`

I am implementing list as below (using generics to use for different object lists)

```
public class PagedList<E> implements List<E>  {
  private List<E> list;
  private long totalRecords; //Getter-setters are added

  public PagedList(List<E> list) {
    super();
    this.list = list;
  }

  public PagedList(List<E> list, long totalRecords) {
    super();
    this.list = list;
    this.totalRecords = totalRecords;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(E element) {
     return this.list.add(element);
  }
  //All other List abstract methods implemented same as above using this.list
}
```

Added [JsonSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) for same: `public class PagedListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<PagedList>` with serialization logic in `serialize()` method. Which is registered using [spring-boot jackson customization](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) :

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.serializerByType(PagedList.class, new PagedListSerializer());
    return builder;
}
```

When I try to `return PagedList<Employee>(list, 1000)`, I am not able to get following response. Its returning same as of normal list. Not executing custom serialization. How to get following paged response?

```
{ 
  list : [{employeeId: "1", name: "John" }, ... ],
  totalRecords : 1000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need custom deserializer to get this json. Just add `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` annotation to your class:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public static class PagedList<E> implements List<E>  {
    @JsonProperty
    private List<E> list;

    @JsonProperty // no need for this if you have getter-setters 
    private long totalRecords; 

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

...
```

Here is full demo: https://gist.github.com/varren/35c4ede769499b1290f98e39a2f85589

**Update after comments:**

I think Spring uses Jacksons `return mapper.writerFor(List.class).writeValueAsString(new MyList());` Here is demo:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public static class MyRestController  {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //returns [] for both 0 and 1
    @RequestMapping(value="test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List test(@RequestParam int user) {
        return user == 0 ? new ArrayList(): new MyList();
    }

    //returns [] for 0 and expected custom {"empty": true} for 1
    @RequestMapping(value="testObj", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object testObj(@RequestParam int user) {
        return user == 0 ? new ArrayList(): new MyList();
    }

    // returns expected custom {"empty": true}
    @RequestMapping(value="testMyList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public MyList testMyList() {
        return new MyList();
    }

    // returns expected custom {"empty": true}
    @RequestMapping(value="testMyListMapper", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testMyListMapper() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(new MyList());
    }

    // returns []
    @RequestMapping(value="testMyListMapperListWriter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testMyListMapperListWriter() throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writerFor(List.class).writeValueAsString(new MyList());
    }
}
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public static class MyList extends ArrayList {}
```

So you have to **Option 1**) return `Object` instead of `List` or **Option 2**) register custom serialifer for **List** (and not for PageList)   `builder.serializerByType(List.class, new PagedListSerializer());` like this:

```
public class PagedListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List> {
  @Override
  public void serialize(List valueObj, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if (valueObj instanceof PagedList) {
      PagedList value = (PagedList) valueObj;
      gen.writeStartObject();
      gen.writeNumberField("totalRecords", value.getTotalRecords());
      gen.writeObjectField("list", value.getList());
      gen.writeEndObject();
    }else{
      gen.writeStartArray();
      for(Object obj : valueObj)
        gen.writeObject(obj);
      gen.writeEndArray();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` and `@JsonProperty`. But it doesn't work for Spring's rest service. ObjectMapper is not using writeValueAsString() method. Here is my source code for reference - [Spring-boot-jdbc-template](https://github.com/govind-s/Spring-Boot-JdbcTemplate)

Comment: @GovindSomani awesome demo. the problem you have there is that you use List<Employee> and not PagedList<Employee> as a return type of your controller method. Jackson is not even looking for PageList deserializer. Changing return type worked for me for both your deserializer and my annotations https://i.gyazo.com/0eccca36d668430be083cb2fe733a207.png

Comment: Yes, you are right. Depend on your **method return type** it serializes according to object config. But I have to keep method type generic, in this as a `List`. As mentioned in actual question, I have to return as normal list also, depend on request parameter for same **api request**. So, I can't return as `PagedList<E>` every-time. New [dao](https://github.com/govind-s/Spring-Boot-JdbcTemplate/blob/paged-list/src/main/java/com/rangers/jdbctemplate/model/dao/EmployeeDaoImpl.java) file in [eg](https://github.com/govind-s/Spring-Boot-JdbcTemplate/tree/paged-list)

Comment: @GovindSomani updated my post. I think you will have to register list serializer then and not `PagedList`, but it's kinda strange decision to be honest. Will be hard to parse this json on client side. Client will have to expect object **OR** array from server and it can be pain to setup with some libraries.

Comment: @GovindSomani btw, Jackson usually can understand object type just fine, but i think there is some spring wraper object involved or some bug for list serialization and it messes things up for responce **And actually i think you don't need to change anything except return `Object`  in your controller** https://i.gyazo.com/9837906d67fd1d994ae61061dc1cb689.png

Comment: I was keeping api's as generic as possible, so that its upto client hot to get response - in array or object (to get totalRecords), depending on flag send in request. And we don't need to change any return type.

Comment: There is one config/method in Spring's ObjectMapper/objectConvertor which you need to add/override to handle serialization depend on instance of class. Anyway, your updated post is also answer for my question (kind of same as adding change in Spring).

Comment: @GovindSomani Can you point me to exact method? i'll add it to my post. Or you could write new answer if you want to

Comment: Solution is, from original question `public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder()` method to serialize `List` instead of `PagedList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create your customObject Mapper and use your serializer there.

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="custom.CustomObjectMapper"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: we can define ObjectMapper as bean to override default one. Can you give some more details to write custom serialization? Here is my source-code for reference- [Spring-boot-jdbc-template](https://github.com/govind-s/Spring-Boot-JdbcTemplate)

Comment: @GovindS were you able to implement custom serialization for List of objects. I'm also trying to do the same but  the custom serializer is not getting executed.

Comment: @Monisha, yes. You can refer [this|https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367400/6108027] answer for reference. Are you using same configuration?